# Can't display data from parent in child component

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

I'm new to Vue.js and trying to build a small application that a user can select a number and view it in another page. The data passed from the parent component was not displayed in the child component like "You select: (a number)", it showed "You select:", without the number passed from the parent. Where did I do wrong? I really can't figure it out.

ParentComponent.vue

```
    <template>
        <div>
            <p>Select a number: 
            <select v-model="num">
                <option disabled value="">Select</option>
                <option v-for="n in 10">{{n}}</option>
                <child-component v-bind:select="num"></child-component>
            </select>
            </p>
        </div>
    </template>

    <script>
    import ChildComponent from '../components/ChildComponent'
    export default {
      name: 'ParentComponent',
      components: {
        "child-component": ChildComponent
      },
      data () {
        return {
          num: 0,
        }
      }
    }
    </script>

    <style scoped>
    </style>
```

ChildComponent.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h2>{{msg}}</h2>
    <p>You select: {{select}}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'ChildComponent',
  props: {
    select: Number
  },
  data () {
    return {
      msg: 'ChildComponent'
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

Comment: Vue js has so called [computed](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) props it should help you

Comment: I wonder why the code doesn't work

Comment: This is because "a cache" of vue js
Vue props and state are lazy, so if you want to compute you properties to update your component, you shoul use computed porps

Comment: If I change "props" to "computed", it shows NaN. What function should I add for the computed props?

Comment: add smth like `getMsg: function(){return this.msg}` and in your view use `<child-component v-bind:select="getMsg"></child-component>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `<child-component>` in the `<select></select>` tags, please pull out it from the select tag and run it.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <p>Select a number: 
        <select v-model="num">
            <option disabled value="">Select</option>
            <option v-for="n in 10">{{n}}</option>
        </select>
        <child-component v-bind:select="num"></child-component> /// run it in here//
        </p>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import ChildComponent from '../components/ChildComponent'
export default {
  name: 'ParentComponent',
  components: {
    "child-component": ChildComponent
  },
  data () {
    return {
      num: 0,
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```